# Store data of different types into a vector<char>?

Tags: c++, casting, generic-programming

I'm trying to write a generic function that casts and stores arguments of different data types into a `vector<char>`. By casting I mean that the bit representation is preserved within the vector of characters. For instance a 4 byte `int` such as `0x19a4f607` will be stored in the vector as `vc[0] = 0x19`, `vc[1] = 0xa4`, `vc[2] = 0xf6` and `vc[3] = 0x07`.

Here is what I have written so far, but I get a segmentation fault. Any idea how I can fix this?

```
template <class T>
void push_T(vector<char>& vc, T n){
  char* cp = (char*)&n;
  copy(cp, cp+sizeof(T), vc.end());
}
```

Comment: How are you planning to make sense of the vector's contents once you've put everything in? Are you trying to serialize something?

Comment: That's right. I know in what order and what data I am encoding, so, I don't have to worry about how to decode my data.

Comment: I'd suggest using unsigned char instead of char to use with address manipulation;where signed data has no significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an iterator that is capable of inserting at the end of the vector; `.begin()` and `.end()` are only capable of modifying existing elements. Try `std::back_inserter(vc)`.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem here is that you haven't made any effort to resize your vector, so you immediately write off the end of the underlying array.  You need to precede the `copy()` call with a `vc.resize(vc.size() + sizeof(T))`, or use a `std::back_inserter` insert iterator to force push_back() behavior on the copy.

Now, I'll assume you have a good reason for subverting the type system in the first place....